# Launching jupyter notebook in Anaconda on Mac, it also opens the terminal. Is this supposed to happen?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

When I want to exit everything, do I first quit terminal or the notebook in browser or what exactly?

EDIT AS REQUESTED: I first launch Anaconda by searching in Spotlight for "Anaconda" and launching it (NOT through the terminal). After Anaconda opens, under Jupyter Notebooks I click "launch" (again not through the terminal). Jupyter Notebooks opens in my default browser but the terminal also opens. My question is, is the terminal also supposed to open as I mentioned or did I do something incorrectly with my installation of Anaconda?

Comment: Whether a terminal opens depends on how you launch. Please *edit your question* and provide more details, so we can propose an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you open notebook terminal also opened. First, quit notebook & then terminal.